# Trouble printing elements in ArrayList from user input

Tags: java, arraylist, multiple-constructors

I am having trouble trying to figure out why my program is not printing  the user input (plane ids,capacity). I edited my code so when the user selects print planes print plane info it works fine. However my original question is different than the duplicate. I am trying to return the planeID, capacity AND destination, departure. I have a toString method already and I don't want to override with another.

Basically the goal of this program is to add planes, the planes destinations/departures, and the planes capacity. Then once they are added have the user select an option for which one they'd like to print. printAllPlanes prints all of the planeIDs and capacity, printAllFlights prints the planeID, capacity and the destintation/departure, and printPlanesInfo prints the planeId/capacity.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        FlightServices fs = new FlightServices();

        UserInput ui = new UserInput(reader, fs);
        ui.start();

        System.out.println("Flight Service");
        System.out.println("----------");

        ui.printing();

    }

}
public class Airport {
    private String planeId;
    private int capacity;
    private String dest;
    private String dep;

    public Airport(String planeId, int capacity) {
        this.planeId = planeId;
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public Airport(String planeId, String dep, String dest) {
        this.dest = dest;
        this.dep = dep;

    }

    public String getPlaneId() {
        return this.planeId;
    }

    public void setPlaneId(String planeId) {
        this.planeId = planeId;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return this.capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return this.dest;
    }

    public void setDestination(String dest) {
        this.dest = dest;
    }

    public String getDeparture() {
        return this.dep;
    }

    public void setDeparture(String dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }

    public String firstString() {
        return planeId + " (" + capacity + ")";
    }

    public String secString() {
        return planeId + " (" + capacity + ")" + "(" + dest + "-" + dep;
    }
}
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FlightServices {
    private ArrayList<Airport> airport;

    public FlightServices() {
        airport = new ArrayList<Airport>();

    }

    public void add(String planeId, int capacity) {
        airport.add(new Airport(planeId, capacity));
    }

    public void addFlight(String planeId, String dest, String dep) {
        airport.add(new Airport(planeId, dest, dep));
    }

    public void printAllPlanes() {
        for (Airport all : airport) {
            System.out.println(all);
        }
    }

    public void printAllFlights() {
        for (Airport all : airport) {
            System.out.println(all);
        }
    }

    public void printPlanesInfo(String planeId) {
        for (Airport info : airport) {
            if (planeId.equals(info.getPlaneId())) {
                info.toString();
            }
        }
    }

}
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInput {
    private Scanner reader;
    private FlightServices fs;

    public UserInput(Scanner reader, FlightServices fs) {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.fs = fs;
    }

    public void start() {

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choose operation: ");
            System.out.println("[1] Add airplane");
            System.out.println("[2] Add flight");
            System.out.println("[3] Exit");

            int input = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
            if (input == 3) {
                break;
            } else if (input == 1) {
                this.addPlane();
            } else if (input == 2) {
                this.addFlight();
            }
        }

    }

    public void addPlane() {
        System.out.println("Give plane ID: ");
        String id = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Give plane capacity: ");
        int capacity = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        this.fs.add(id, capacity);
    }

    public void addFlight() {
        System.out.println("Give plane ID: ");
        String id = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Give departure airport code: ");
        String dep = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Give destination airport code: ");
        String des = reader.nextLine();

        this.fs.addFlight(id, dep, des);
    }

    public void printing() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Choose operation: ");
            System.out.println("[1] Print planes");
            System.out.println("[2] Print flights");
            System.out.println("[3] Print plane info");
            System.out.println("[4] Quit");

            int command = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
            if (command == 4) {
                break;
            } else if (command == 1) {
                this.fs.printAllPlanes();
            } else if (command == 2) {
                this.fs.printAllFlights();
            } else if (command == 3) {
                this.addPlaneInfo();
            }

        }

    }

    public void addPlaneInfo() {
        System.out.println("Give plane ID: ");
        String id = reader.nextLine();

        this.fs.printPlanesInfo(id);

    }

}
```

Comment: Give your main classes valid `toString()` methods.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes however, how would I print out the second string, the one underneath my toString()? I need that so I can print out the flights dep/dest.

Comment: You would craft your `toString()` method to do just that. If the class contains other objects, then `toString()` could possibly call *their* `toString()` methods.